# Filling in missing data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I was hoping you would be able to help me solve a small problem.
I am using a small device that prints out two properties that I save to a file. The device rasters in X and Y direction to form a grid. I am interested in plotting the relative intensity of these two properties as a function of the X and Y dimensions. I record the data in 4 columns that are comma separated (X, Y, property 1, property 2). 
The grid is examined in lines, so for each Y value, it will move from X1 to X2 which are separated several millimeters apart. Then it will move to the next line and over again.

I am able to process the data in python with pandas/numpy but it doesn't work too well when there are any missing rows (which unfortunately does happen). 
I have attached a sample of the output (and annotated the problems):

```
44,11,500,1
45,11,120,2
46,11,320,3
47,11,700,4
New            << used as my Y axis separator
44,12,50,5
45,12,100,6
46,12,1500,7
47,12,2500,8
```

Sometimes, however a line or a few will be missing making it not possible to process and plot. Currently I have not been able to automatically fix it and have to do it manually. The **bad** output looks like this:

```
44,11,500,1
45,11,120,2
46,11,320,3
47,11,700,4
New         << used as my Y axis separator
45,12,100,5 << missing 44,12...
46,12,1500,6
47,12,2500,7
```

I know the number of lines I expect since I know my range of X and Y.

What would be the best way to deal with this? Currently I manually enter the missing X and Y values and populate property 1 and 2 with values of 0. This can be time consuming and I would like to automate it. I have two questions.

Question 1: How can I automatically fill in my missing data with the corresponding values of X and Y and two zeros? This could be obtained from a pre-generated array of X and Y values that correspond to the experimental range.

Question 2: Is there a better way to split the file into separate arrays for plotting (rather than using the 'New' line?) For instance, by having a 'if' function that will output each line between X(start) and X(end) to a separate array? I've tried doing that but with no success.

I've attached my current (crude) code:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('FileName.csv', delimiter = ',', skiprows=0)
 rows = [-1] + np.where(df['X']=='New')[0].tolist() + [len(df.index)]
 dff = {}
 for i, r in enumerate(rows[:-1]):
     dff[i] = df[r+1: rows[i+1]]
 maxY = len(dff)
 data = []
 data2 = []
 for yaxes in range(0, maxY): 
     data2.append(dff[yaxes].ix[:,2])
 <data2 is then used for plotting using matplotlib>
```

To answer my Question 1, I was thinking about using the 'reindex' and 'reset_index' functions, however haven't managed to make them work.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this meet what you want?

Q1: fill `X` using `reindex`, and others using `fillna`

Q2: Passing separated `StringIO` to `read_csv` is easier (change if you use Python 3)

```
# read file and split the input 
f = open('temp.csv', 'r')
chunks = f.read().split('New')

# read csv as separated dataframes, using first column as index
dfs = [pd.read_csv(StringIO(unicode(chunk)), header=None, index_col=0) for chunk in chunks]

def pad(df):
    # reindex, you should know the range of x
    df = df.reindex(np.arange(44, 48)) 

    # pad y from forward / backward, assuming y should have the single value
    df[1] = df[1].fillna(method='bfill')
    df[1] = df[1].fillna(method='ffill')
    # padding others
    df = df.fillna(0)
    # revert index to values
    return df.reset_index(drop=False)

dfs = [pad(df) for df in dfs]

dfs[0]
#     0   1    2  3
# 0  44  11  500  1
# 1  45  11  120  2
# 2  46  11  320  3
# 3  47  11  700  4

# dfs[1]
#     0   1     2  3
# 0  44  12     0  0
# 1  45  12   100  5
# 2  46  12  1500  6
# 3  47  12  2500  7
```

Answer (score 0):

### First Question

---

I've included print statements inside function to explain how this function works

```
In [89]:     
    def replace_missing(df , Ids ):
        # check what are the mssing values
        missing = np.setdiff1d(Ids , df[0])

        if len(missing) > 0 :
            missing_df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.zeros( (len(missing) , 4 )))
            #print('---missing df---')
            #print(missing_df)
            missing_df[0] = missing
            #print('---missing df---')
            #print(missing_df)
            missing_df[1].replace(0 , df[1].iloc[0] , inplace = True)
            #print('---missing df---')
            #print(missing_df)
            df = pd.concat([df , missing_df])
            #print('---final df---')
            #print(df)
        return df

    ​
In [91]:
Ids = np.arange(44,48)
final_df = df1.groupby(df1[1] , as_index = False).apply(replace_missing , Ids).reset_index(drop = True)
final_df
Out[91]:
0   1   2      3
44  11  500    1
45  11  120    2
46  11  320    3
47  11  700    4
45  12  100    5
46  12  1500   6
47  12  2500   7
44  12  0      0
```

### Second question

---

```
In [92]:
group = final_df.groupby(final_df[1])

In [99]:
separate = [group.get_group(key) for key in group.groups.keys()]

separate[0]
Out[104]:
0   1   2   3
44  11  500 1
45  11  120 2
46  11  320 3
47  11  700 4
```